# Laravel eloquent relations not working completely

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've a payment gateway, I want to access the product items after returning, so I created several tables Payments, Orders, OrderItems and configured the relationships between them.
Each Payment is for one Order and each Order contains several OrderItem and each OrderItem contains one product. Now I want to access each Product through an object of the Payment Model, which returns the following error.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
> 1054 Unknown column 'orders.order_item_id' in 'field list' (SQL:
> select `products`.*, `orders`.`order_item_id` as `laravel_through_key`
> from `products` inner join `orders` on `orders`.`id` =
> `products`.`order_id` where `orders`.`order_item_id` = 68 limit 1)

```
$product_order_item = $payment->order->order_items->map(function ($order_item) {
            dd($order_item->product);
        });
```

Payment Model:

```
protected $table = "payments";
protected $guarded = [];

public function order() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
}
```

Order Model:

```
protected $table = "orders";
protected $guarded = [];

public function payment() {
    return $this->hasOne(Payment::class);
}

public function order_items() {
    return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
}
```

OrderItem Model:

```
protected $table = "order_items";
protected $guarded = [];

public function order() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
}

public function product() {
    return $this->hasOneThrough(Product::class, Order::class);
}
```

Product Model:

```
protected $table = "products";
protected $guarded = [];

public function order_items() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(OrderItem::class);
}
```

That is migrations:

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('CASCADE');
            $table->unsignedInteger('amount');
            $table->unsignedInteger('res_code');
            $table->enum('status', ['paid', 'unpaid']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

=====================================================

```
Schema::create('order_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('CASCADE');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('CASCADE');

            $table->unsignedInteger('price');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

===========================================================

```
Schema::create('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('CASCADE');
            $table->enum('status', ['paid', 'unpaid']);
            $table->unsignedInteger('ref_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('res_id');
            $table->enum('gateway', ['idpay', 'zarinpal']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

what is the problem?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why is the product relation in your OrderItem model a hasOneThrough? I would expect it to be a one-to-one relation? That is where your problem is. I think you misunderstand what hasOneThrough is and you are overcomplicating things

Comment: The Products table is not directly related to OrderItems. 
However I used the hasOne method and it gave this error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.order_item_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`order_item_id` = 69 and `products`.`order_item_id` is not null limit 1)

Comment: Hi, can you please show your Payment, Order, and OrderItem's migration?

Comment: Post edited and migrations added

Answer (score 0):

You should use `belongsTo` for the `product` relationship of `OrderItem` Model

**OrderItem Model:**

```
public function product() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

And `hasMany` for the `order_items` relationship of `Product` Model

**Product Model:**

```
public function order_items() {
    return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many